# Windows Form Designer shrunk and moved the controls after changing DPI scale settings, how do I reverse it?

Tags: size, scale, reset, designer, dpi

I was playing with the scale zoom DPI settings from 100% to 150% and it shrunk and moved all the controls in the windows designer.

Please help, how do I reset it back to normal at 100%?

[image]

I tried setting it back to 100% but it won't work.